# Clustering based on upper and lower limit of distance between points

Tags: python, postgis, clustering

My dataset is like

```
points         time          device_id
```

How do I find clusters where points are between a certain min and max distance of each other, for example between 10 and 50 metres of each other?

I know ST_ClusterDBSCAN will make clusters based on ONLY the higher threshold limit, i.e. points within 50 meters or less. but this does NOT take into account the lower threshold limit of 10 m

Comment: Have you considered using buffers and testing for intersections?  Something like `select from table as a, table as b where a.id != b.id and st_coveredby(a.geom,st_buffer(b.geom,50)) and not st_coveredby(a.geom,st_buffer(b.geom,10);`

Comment: This is a pretty tough question. Can you provide a reason why you wouldn't cluster things that are under 10 m? What would happen when A is more than 10m from B and C, but B is less than 10m from C? Would A+B+C be a single cluster or would A+B and A+C be two clusters?